# Python, Import a class inside a long chain of directories

Tags: python, module

I have a work directory as follow :

```
myProject
--dir1
----__init__.py
----file1.py
--dir2
----__init__.py
----file2.py
--dir3
----__init__.py
----dir4
------__init__.py
------file3.py
--main.py
```

I want my main.py to work like that :

```
import dir1 
import dir2
import dir3

...
...
myObject1 = dir1.file1.myClass1()
myObject2 = dir2.file2.myClass2()
myObject3 = dir3.dir4.file3.myClass3()
```

The imports works but I get the error :
`AttributeError: module 'dir1' has no attribute 'file1'`

Is there a way to do that ?

In the future, I will have many more files and directories so I cannot use `from *** import ****` because that would make too many imports and it wouldn't be readable. What I want is to only import the `dir1, dir2, dir3` and the user's arguments to the main function will decide which paths to take for `myObject1, myObject2, myObject3`

Thank you very much

Comment: "the user's arguments to the main function will decide which paths to take" - I already thought your question was showing worries about a problem should not reasonably have al all (it points at some seriously underlying design issues), but that phrase shows that you're trying to do something that many starting developers (Python or otherwise) get wrong. If the user needs to know anything about the internal structure of your code, you've failed to correctly separate data from code. If you explain what you hope to achieve by that, others will be able to explain what a better solution would be.

Comment: Hello, the user doesn't know about the internal structure. He will enter some inputs on an app and I want to create specific objects based on those inputs. Is there a way to do that while preserving the file tree I have ?

Comment: Ok I have fixed my issue. I'm adding `import dir1.file1` in the dir1 __init__ and etc for the rest. I wish there was a way to do it without going back to the __init__ every time I add a new file tho. I tried `from dir1 import *`but this gave the same error as before

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything in your __ init__.py files?  dir1/__ init__.py, for example should include something like:

```
__all__ = ['file1']
```

If you include code for dir1/* files, it might be easier for people to give an answer.

Comment: Hello, my __init__ were all empty but even if I add your line, it won't work. Do you mean you want the code in file1.py ? Is it relevant to this issue ? I won't be able to share them unfortunately but it just contains the code for myClass1, same for the other files

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have fixed my issue.

In the dir1 `__init__` file, I add the line `import dir1.file1` and same for the rest.

It's a bit annoying because it means I will have to update each **init** file everytime I add a new file. If someone has a solution that avoids it, it would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic imports can be done with [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).